# Removing RAID-Treating drives independently

Tags: raid

I have a server with a *3ware Inc 9750 SAS2/SATA-II RAID PCIe* controller.

The server has a non-RAID disk for the OS and 4x1TB disks in RAID-5 to store data.

For reasons that have more to do with the re-purposing of the system and human capital rather than technology, we want to revert to a simpler configuration without a RAID. Ideally, we would like to keep the OS disk as is and mount each one of the other disks independently.

Is there a way to use the RAID controller just as a disk controller (no hardware or software RAID configuration) to achieve this? If not, is there a different way to do this?

Thank you,

George

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the controller firmware, there are usually two ways of doing this.  Some controllers offer a "JBOD" setting that passes the individual disks though.  Other controllers require you to set up a bunch of single disk RAID0 groups, which essentially does the same thing.  Just a little more work.

I couldn't find instructions for that particular controller, but if you get into the RAID configuration, you should be able to figure it out.  If not, post the options you see.

Also, just a friendly reminder - modifying the existing RAID set will essentially destroy all of the data currently in RAID5.

Comment: If tw_cli is being used, you set it up just like you're creating a RAID array but specify `type=single` (instead of raid1, raid5 etc).  IIRC a 'JBOD' in 3ware parlance on the 9xxx controllers is simply an unconfigured drive.  I believe there's a BIOS setting to export JBOD, but that's not necessary.  Create a unit of type single.

Comment: Thank you both (@jimg, @yoonix). Just to clarify, by creating this type of "single" RAID per disk configuration, the only dependency I will then have to the RAID controller is to access the disks for mounting as if it is a glorified disk controller.  Therefore, the only time I will need to interact with tw_cli would be when replacing (or adding more single instance) disks, correct?